# Navigation can't find screen if states condition is in Stack.Navigator

Tags: react-native, navigation

When I want to navigate from Home screen to Login screen I get error:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:173 The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Login"} was not handled by any navigator. Do you have a screen named 'Login'?
```

**routes.js:**

```
import LoginScreen from '../screens/login/login';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/home/home';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  const [userToken, setuserToken] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    _bootstrapAsync = async () => {      
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');    

      if (userToken) { 
        setuserToken(token)
      } 

    }
    _bootstrapAsync()
  })    

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {userToken == null ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
         ) : ( 
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
         )} 
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );

}

export default App;
```

**home.js:**

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Text, Button, Content } from 'native-base';

const HomeScreen = (props) => {
  const { navigation } = props

  handleLogout = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    navigation.navigate('Login');
  };

    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <Button full onPress={handleLogout}>
            <Text>Log Out</Text>
          </Button>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );

}

export default HomeScreen;
```

If in routes.js I remove userToken states condition, and in Stack.Navigator is only:

```
  <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
```

I can successfully navigate from Home to Login screen.
But this approach is not good, because I need to have checking if token is present in Storage.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You will be having a route named login if userToken == null is true, but in this condition as you are in Home screen than you will be not able to navigate to login screen as the condition is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not able to find the Login route until your condition is true, that's the reason you are not able to find the Login route

change

```
{userToken == null ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
         ) : ( 
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
         )} 

to

{userToken == null ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
         ) : ( 
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
         )}
```

Hope this helps!